# ScrollView contains ViewPager and ExpandListView - Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager, android-scrollview

I have a LinearLayout contains a ViewPager and an ExpandableListView in vertical.

I put all them in a ScrollView. Now ScrollView contains a LinearLayout (ViewPager + ExpandableListView).

But ViewPager doesn't display.

I want all put inside a ScrollView.

---

UPDATE :

I have fixed my problem by using addHeaderView(), an attribute of ExpandableListView.

Thank for all reply.

Comment: Please provide code here instead of providing the link to zip file many of the users will not be interested downloading the zip file. anyways thanks for the link it can be helpful for me in future...:)

Comment: Code is too long. Plz help me.

Comment: *"I put all them in a ScrollView"* & *"I want all put inside a ScrollView."* - Why? An `ExpandableListView` is already scrollable, so it doesn't make sense to wrap it in yet another scrollable widget. Normally, a `ViewPager` with scrollable content should be plenty.

Comment: Is there anyway to resolve my problem ? I want to scroll all page in vertical, not single  ExpandableListView.

Comment: If you want to make the whole page scrollable, and a significant part of the content is visualized through a list, consider adding the remaining views as a header to the (`Expandable`)`ListView`.

Comment: @MH : U mean consider ViewPager as a header to the ExpandableListView, such as groupPosition = 0 and this has no childItem ?

Comment: @anh.tuan: No, not if your `ExpandableListView` is a page and you want to be able to swipe to other pages two. I'm still unsure about what you're actually trying to accomplish by wrapping everything in a `ScrollView`. I think it'd be best if you edit your question and elaborate a bit on your what you're after. A couple of mockups of the current situation and your end goal probably wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: @MH : ViewPager is a header. It's auto-swipe between 5 focus -images of a News App. Exactly it's 5 focus articles. ExpandableListView is below, description list of articles. That all i mean. Plz leave your email. I send u exactly what i want.

Comment: I'm happy to help (here on SO, not via private email though), but still think that your question would benefit from a more concise description and some mockups. For example, I'm not sure how to visualize "5 focus images/articles" with an `ExpandableListView`. Without that information, I can only makes guesses as to what you're after. Part of getting a 'good' answer to your question is to [ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: First I'm sorry for my description. You can see my detail code at http://www.mediafire.com/download/h99l06zncko8nah/MultiLayerExpandable.zip . ViewPager is auto-swipe beetween 5 focus images/articles, below is an indicator, then an ExpandableListView. ViewPager is auto-swipe and not affect to ExpandableListView below. When you run my code, you will see that. I want to make the whole page scrollable. Wait for your reply. Thank.